# Replace words in a file with specified replacement string and handle indent level

Tags: python, indentation, text-processing, code-translation

So i have an exercise. I have to write a python script that finds all files in the actual folder with '.prog' extension. (This part of the program already works). This prog file looks like something like this:

```
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1]) ;print "Start of the program!"

LOOP i in range(1,n) [[print "The number:";print i]]

DECISION n < 5 [[print n ;print "smaller then 5"]]
```

**The output should be this:**

```
import sys  

n = int(sys.argv[1]) 
print "Start of the program!"

for i in range(1,n) :
    print "The number:"
    print i

if n < 5 :
    print n 
    print "smaller then 5"
```

So i have to replace LOOP to for and DECISION to if. It can be a space before the ';', but it cant after it. The '[[**]]' always contains python statements.
After the for loops and if statements the commands always have to start after four spaces.
This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def find():
import glob, os
os.chdir(os.getcwd())
for file in glob.glob("*.prog"):
    ProgToPy(file)


def  ProgToPy(f):
outname = f.replace("prog","py")
replacements = {'LOOP':'for',  'DECISION':'if', ' ;':'\n', ';':'\n    ', ' [[':' :\n    ', ']]':''}
with open(f) as infile, open(outname, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)

find()
```

The problem with this that my output looks like this:

```
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])
print "Start of the program!"

for i in range(1,n) :
    print "The number:"
    print i

if n < 5 :
    print n
print "smaller then 5"
```

And if i put in something like this in the replacements `' ;':'\n    '`. The first print will starts right in after the four spaces. Then the created `.py` file don't work properly.

Comment: Can you use regular expressions?

Comment: Yes, sorry i felt to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the semi-colon works differently based on its location, you should essentially write separate functions for each state. The `[[...]]` represent a block scope in Python, so let's call these states `normal state` and `block state`.

To control for the state, we'll use a boolean variable `in_block` and use regex to determine its value.

Here, I put all the replacement tasks in a `replaceTokens` function.

```
def replaceTokens(statement, in_block=False):
    if in_block:
        statement = statement.replace(SEMI, NEWLINE+TABSPACE)
        statement = statement.replace(OPEN_BRACKETS, COLON+NEWLINE+TABSPACE)
    else:
        statement = statement.replace(SEMI, NEWLINE)
        statement = statement.replace(OPEN_BRACKETS, COLON+NEWLINE)

    statement = statement.replace(CLOSE_BRACKETS, NEWLINE)

    statement = statement.replace(LOOP, FOR)
    statement = statement.replace(DECISION, IF)

    return statement
```

Above code looks quite tedious, but if you wanted you could easily write a `for` loop for that. The important take away here is the fact that I'm using the boolean variable `in_block`. That allows you to decide whether to follow the newline with a tab or not depending on the presence of the double-brackets.

To find the statements within the block scope, I use regex:

```
def progToPy(f):
    outname = f.replace("prog","py")
    rf = open(f, "r")
    text = rf.read()

    rf.close()

    block_regex = re.compile(r'\[\[.*\]\]')
    mo = block_regex.findall(text)

    for match in mo:
        statement = blockScope(match)
        text = text.replace(match, statement)

    text = replaceTokens(text)
    print(text)
```

The `blockScope` function replaces *only* the statements within the block scope using `in_block=True`, then replaces those parts first. Then, when we call `replaceTokens` on the entire document, those in the block scope have already been replaced and therefore won't be affected by the second call.

```
def blockScope(block):
    statement = replaceTokens(block, in_block=True)
    return statement
```

Comment: Okey so this works fine. But what if the input file looks like this:

    `import sys  

    n = int(sys.argv[1]) ;print "Start of the program!"

    LOOP i in range(1,n) [[print "The numbers:";LOOP j in range(1,3)
    [[print j]] ;print i ;LOOP k in range(1,3) [[print k]] ;print "This is the end of 
    the program!"]]

    DECISION n < 5 [[print n ;print "lesser then 5"]]`

Comment: @TheFall You could use an additional variable `current_indent` and add or subtract 4 based on the presence of `[[` and `]]`.

Comment: How could i use that? I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for solving your problem.

```
import re
import glob, os

pattern = r'(.*)\[\[(.*)\]\]'
regex = re.compile(pattern)

def ProgToPy(f):
    outname = f.replace("prog","py")    
    replacements = {'LOOP':'for',  'DECISION':'if', ';': '\n\t'}

    with open(f) as infile, open(outname, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            m = regex.match(line)

            if m:
                line = ''
                for matched_part in m.groups():
                    line += matched_part + '\n\t'

            for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
                line = line.replace(src, target)

            outfile.write(line)

os.chdir(os.getcwd())
for file in glob.glob("*.prog"):
    ProgToPy(file)
```